# bfd.h should have included libiberty/ansidecl.h in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc, binutils

binutils package seems to be changed, as it includes directory of `libiberty.h` has moved to `/usr/include/libiberty`, thus there is possible a wrong include in `bfd.h` regarding `ansidecl.h`.

Getting those compile errors when using binutils trace utilities

```
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h: In function ‘basename’:
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h:110:38: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL’
 extern char *basename (const char *) ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL(1); 
                                      ^
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h:121:45: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL’
 extern const char *lbasename (const char *) ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL(1); 
                                             ^
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h:126:49: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL’
 extern const char *dos_lbasename (const char *) ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL(1);
                                                 ^
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h:132:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL’
 extern const char *unix_lbasename (const char *) ATTRIBUTE_RETURNS_NONNULL ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL(1);
```

By changing `bfd.h` to include `/usr/include/libiberty/ansidecl.h`, everything went fine in my compilation.

Please, any hints for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As reported by *Eduardo Abinader* (the author of question) and *Shaun Jackman* as [Bug 58689](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58689) and [MSG 00135](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2014-08/msg00135.html) respectively, concluding from exchanged data...

**This is an issue caused by older library installation on Ubuntu system, I guess it is fault of neither Ubuntu nor binutils, but looks like System Update issue.** Solution is included in question itself.

PS: But, the main thing is we had an answer back then and now. More details can be found on Links! Please improve this answer if required. :)